# Sequence to sequence autoencoder - decoder input?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, autoencoders

What's the input to the decoder part of a sequence to sequence autoencoder? I've seen certain examples of such an autoencoder (using LSTM's more often than not) but am still unclear.

- For example, here in this often-cited [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6506/d13a84f90f8620fd028cfe5b8b9d0444a6d2.pdf) by Dai & Le ('Semi
  Supervised Sequence Learning'), we have the following diagram:

  [image: Dai & Le]

  What's the input to the decoder portion of the autoencoder here? In this example it's 'W-X-Y-Z.' But in general, is
  it the same as the input to the encoder? Or is it using the output
  from the previous timestep/LSTM cell as input?
- Similarly, in another popular [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.04681.pdf) by Srivastava et. al
  ('Unsupervised Learning of Video Representations using LSTMs'), they
  have the following diagram:

  [image: Srivastava et al]

  It seems they're using the reversed input from the encoder as input
  here. However, there's a section as follows:

  > The decoder can be of two kinds – conditional or unconditioned. A conditional decoder receives the last generated output frame as
  >   input, i.e., the dotted input in Fig. 2 is present. An unconditioned
  >   decoder does not receive that input.

  In the unconditioned decoder, what input does the decoder receive?

Thank you! I'm new here, so please be kind :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the *Semi-supervised Sequence Learning* paper correctly, the input to the decoder-portion of the autoencoder is the same as it would be for an ordinary language model. The authors state:

> We also find that recurrent language models [2, 24] can be used as a pretraining method for LSTMs. This is equivalent to removing the encoder part of the sequence autoencoder in Figure 1

Thus, it should be the same input that is fed to the encoder. The difference, then, would be that the hidden state of the decoder is initialized with the last hidden state of the encoder.